# How to save Editable div content in local storage.

Tags: javascript, html

I am try to make small application there i have some editable dives so now i need to make setup if user refresh page than editable dives content store in local storage via JavaScript and update local storage after every 20 sec.Is that possible.

For example.

**HTML**

```
<div contentEditable='true'; >Job Title</div>

<div contentEditable='true'; >Email/Other</div>
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('someElement', document.getElementById('someElement').innerHTML);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="job" contentEditable="true"></div>
<div id="email" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 document.getElementById('job').innerHTML = localStorage['job'] || 'Job Title';
 document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = localStorage['email'] || 'Email/Other';

 setInterval(function() {
      localStorage['job'] = document.getElementById('job').innerHTML;
      localStorage['email'] = document.getElementById('email').innerHTML;
 }, 20 * 1000);
```

Comment: How can i check that dives content save and how to retrieve when page refresh.

Comment: @ZohiabAhmad, the retrieval is done by the first two lines. The saving is done by the last four.

Comment: Thanks.but please conform that how can detect dynamically storage data i mean about answer you sad  in code first two lines you used my example content but when my content change so than how can i retrieve i mean what was in before refresh.

Comment: @ZohiabAhmad, the example content is used only if the content has not already been saved in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
  localStorage.jobTitle = document.getElementById('div-id').innerHTML;
  localStorage.email = document.getElementById('the-other-div-id').innerHTML;
}, 20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(
        function(){
                if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
              {
                  localStorage.lastname=document.getElementById("result").value;
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Last name: " + localStorage.lastname;
                }
            else
            {
                alert("Sorry, web storage not supported");
             }
             },3000
         );

    </script>
```

try this code it works on every 3 seconds you can increase 3000 to 20000 for 20 seconds